# url to access data from foursquare API does not work

Tags: api, foursquare

I want to access data throughthe foursquare API using the foursquare ID of a given establishement. I have the following data:

```
client_ip = "AAA"
client_secret = "BBB"
id_place = "4c4192d5d7fad13a8cb807da"
```

Why the next URL does not access the data for this particular establishment?

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=AAA&client_secret=BBB/4c4192d5d7fad13a8cb807da

What I get is the following

```
  {
  "meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "errorType": "invalid_auth",
    "errorDetail": "Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details.",
    "requestId": "5900bcf84c1f6734f1ee6b02"
  },
  "response": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read through the Foursquare documentation on [venue details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues). Your request is not formatted correctly.

The following request should get you the details for that venue:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4c4192d5d7fad13a8cb807da?client_id=AAA&client_secret=BBB&v=20170101

Comment: That was really helpful. It worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @DanielBestardDelgado if the answer was helpful please mark it as correct. Thanks!